# Filter data from excel using python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7eBdF.png) I want to filter out some columns base on a country name using python and pandas... Filter excel file base on column A which contains country name...

Comment: First, you need to read the excel file into the pandas data frame. Looking at the image you shared, it won't be trivial to directly read the excel file into data frame. You might need to do some basic file operations first to get the proper data frame. Once you are able to read the excel file into data frame, filtering out is quite trivial by using the following line of code: filtered_df = df[df['ColumnName'] == 'SpecificValue'], here ColumnName will be the field name on the basis of which you want to filter and SpecificValue will be the value on the basis of which you want to filter.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:
my data are in `CSV` file like below, I do filter `e2` column with value `26`.then `filter_1` is filtered value

my input data:

```
+------+-------+----------+----+----+
| area | date  |    e1    | e2 | e3 |
+------+-------+----------+----+----+
|    1 |  4137 |  7312012 | 26 | R  |
|    1 |  4137 |  8212012 | 27 | R  |
|    1 |  4137 | 11062012 | 29 |    |
|    1 | 45353 |  7312012 | 26 | D  |
+------+-------+----------+----+----+
```

code:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv('all.csv')
print(df)
filter_1=df[df['e2']==26]
print(filter_1)
```

output data

```
+------+-------+---------+----+----+
| area | date  |   e1    | e2 | e3 |
+------+-------+---------+----+----+
|    1 |  4137 | 7312012 | 26 | R  |
|    1 | 45353 | 7312012 | 26 | D  |
+------+-------+---------+----+----+
```